# Seeking dinosaur data

Tags: dinosaurs

Is there any open data concerning dinosaur discoveries? I am particularly interested in plotting them on a map, and showing date when clicked/showing all discoveries of a certain type/in a certain time period, from a certain era, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Paleobiology Database](https://paleobiodb.org/#/) is a Creative Commons database that seeks to "provide global, collection-based occurrence and taxonomic data for organisms of all geological ages."  The data can be [downloaded](https://paleobiodb.org/classic/displayDownloadGenerator) in CSV/JSON/RIS, viewed interactively with the [PBDB Navigator](https://paleobiodb.org/navigator/), and accessed programmatically via the API of the [PBDB Data Service](https://paleobiodb.org/data1.2/)